# time delta parameter in python script

Tags: datetime, python-2.7

I am a novice user of Python 2.7.  I have script which outputs a sorted series of date & timestamps and timedeltas (relative to previous date & timestamp):

```
2014-02-11 12:11:38.303000   0:00:00
2014-02-11 12:30:36.851000   0:18:58.548000
2014-02-11 13:58:33.776000   1:27:56.925000
2014-02-11 14:53:49.193000   0:55:15.417000
2014-02-12 09:32:40.186000   18:38:50.993000
2014-02-12 09:32:40.187000   0:00:00.001000
2014-02-12 09:37:50.535000   0:05:10.348000
2014-02-12 14:00:14.496000   4:22:23.961000
2014-02-13 08:51:52.554000   18:51:38.058000
2014-02-13 09:04:47.179000   0:12:54.625000
2014-02-13 09:05:26.359000   0:00:39.180000
```

I am trying to incorporate and apply the following functionality (using some example values below):

```
time_parameter = 40000 #user-defined value in milliseconds (40000=40 seconds)
last_timestamp = 2014-02-13 09:04:47.179000
current_timestamp = 2014-02-13 09:05:26.359000
time_delta = 0:00:39.180000

if time_delta >= time_parameter:
    state = "expired"
else:
    state = "ongoing"
```

My question mainly involves how to write this time-parameter so that the script understands it is using milliseconds and I can utilize this value in the if clause.  I am practicing with some various uses of strftime but running into some frustration with finding a solution.  Hoping to find some answers or guidance.

thanks

edit notes:

time calc:

```
lastdtts = "default"
#...looping through timestamps with format: "14-02-11 08:35:41.526000"
    TimeStamp = line[0]      
    dtts = datetime.strptime(TimeStamp,"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    if lastdtts == "default":
        lastdtts = dtts
    tdelta=dtts-lastdtts
    lastdtts = dtts
    print "%s %s"%(dtts,tdelta) # 2014-02-13 09:05:26.359000   0:00:39.180000
```

Comment: `time_delta = 0:00:39.180000` is not valid Python syntax.  How are you getting time_delta?  Have you gotten the value yet?  Do you only have a string like `"0:00:39.180000"`?  Did you difference two datetimes that you had converted via mktime?

Comment: time_delta (actually "tdelta") is the difference between two datetimes.  I appended my post with the code used.  I was not familiar with mktime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `time_delta` is of type `timedelta` then you can convert the number of millsecond into the same type:

```
limit_msec = 40000    # user-defined value in milliseconds
limit_timedelta = timedelta( milliseconds=limit_msec )
```

and then you can test it:

```
if time_delta >= limit_timedelta:
    state = "expired"
```

Comment: I tried this method and it works!  If you have additional suggestions or tips please feel free to share them with me.  Thank you!